# Connect to a remote mysql server

Tags: java, mysql, database-connection

I am developing a JavaSE application using Netbeans, which is connecting to my local MySQL server.

Is it possible to connect to a remote MySQL server (on different PC).

Comment: Used better description of problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible indeed.

But you have to make sure Mysql is configured to listen to remote connections in addition to localhost (look for the `bind-address` parameter in the my.cnf config file), and open the required ports on the machine that hosts the database.

Finally, the connection string ("`mysql://...`") in your application should be modified to point to those new host and port.

Comment: modify the connection such that the host will be the ip address of the remote database and its port?

Comment: Exactly. Instead of `jdbc:mysql://localhost/test`, you should have something like `jdbc:mysql://192.168.1.50:3306/test` (your values may be different, of course)

Comment: does this need an internet connection, I am sorry for my ignorance,

Comment: Not if your database is on a machine on the same local network (for example, if you have 2 PCs at home connected to the same router, or if your database is hosted on your company's private network).
Having to specify an IP address does not mean you have to have an internet connection ; some ranges are reserved to denote local networks, and 192.168.xxx.xxx is one of them.

Comment: I am sorry but I am confused as to what ip address should. Is it the internal ip or the external

Comment: If the machine that hosts your DB is on your internal (home or enterprise) network and is visible as 192.168.1.1 for example, use that IP. If the machine is somewhere else and only accessible via Internet (say, managed by some hosting provider like PlanetHoster), you should then use the public IP of that machine.